# Passing variable grep command

Tags: bash, awk

A given text file (say foo*.txt) data as follow.

```
1 g = 0.54 0.00   
2 g = 0.32 0.00  
3 g = 0.45 0.00
...
5000 g = 0.5 0.00
```

Basically, I want to extract 10 lines before and after the matching line (including the matching line). The matching line contains 59 characters that contain strings, spaces and numbers.

I have a script as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for file in file*.txt;
do
var=$(command_to_extract_var) # 59 characters containing strings, spaces and numbers
                              # to get this var, I use grep and head
grep -C 10 "$var" "$file"
done > bar.csv
```

Running script by bash -x script_name.sh gives the following:

```
+ for file in 'foo*.txt'
++ grep 'match_pattern' foo1.txt
++ awk '{print $6}'
++ head -n1
++ grep '[0-9]'
+ basis=150
++ grep 'match_pattern' foo1.txt
++ tail -n1
++ awk '{print $3}'
+ number=25
++ grep '[0-9] f = ' foo.txt
++ tail -n150
```

This is followed by a number of lines (even up to 1000) like

> 001 h =  0.000000000000000E+00 e =  3.543218084205956E+00

Finally,

**File name too long**

```
+ final=
+ grep -C 10 '' foo1.txt
```

The output I expect is (one column from each file):

```
0.54   0.62  0.36 ... 0.45
0.32   3.25  0.89 ... 0.25
0.45   0.96  0.14 ... 0.14
...    ....  .... ... 0.96
0.25   0.00  7.23 ... 0.77
```

Comment: `I use following command to extract necessary information from foo.txt`: Provide sample input text and expected output.

Comment: You can use the `$` notation before the variable to pass the variable value to the command i.e. `head -n "${var1}"`. But what are you trying to do with bunch of `tac/grep/head/awk` commands? State your input and expected output clearly  to get a more elegant way to solve your problem

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but if everything is coming from the files you read, why not just loop over each file, extract `var1` and `var2` and then operate on the file, write what you need out, the repeat for the next file in your list? Like `while read -r file; do ## your stuff; done < <(find . -type f ...)`?

Comment: Using grep for search in the first 600 lines of the input taken in reverse order :) amazing and I'll be short here. Just combine grep and awk in one statement

Comment: What is the use of the first variable, if the second one is the row number already?

Comment: `$(( ))` is arithmetic syntax. You can't put a command in there.

Comment: To make this answerable, see the [mcve] definition.

Comment: Also, the size of your variable matters: There's a limit on maximum command-line argument length, and while it's quite large (typically over 128k), environment variable size counts against it too, so if you're `export`ing big variables, there goes your limit. But point being, it has nothing to do with "strings, spaces and numbers" being problematic by nature.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the variable contains 59 characters.

Comment: Run with `bash -x yourscript` and see what it's **actually** doing.

Comment: (which is to say -- could you use `bash -x` to log the commands that are run during execution, and then post the one most immediately prior to the error here?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Have added the the log to the commands.

Comment: What are the lines **directly above** "File name too long"? (Those are the ones that caused the error). The lines *below* the error just tell you its aftermath, not its cause.

Comment: ...if what you have *directly above* the error is file content, then your problem is that content is being used as part of a command line (and it's no surprise that it's too long to be a valid filename).

Comment: (If you don't want to mix up output with the log of which commands are run, note that the log is on stderr -- so if you redirect stdout to `/dev/null` or a file, the xtrace log will be left alone).

Comment: To be clear, telling me that the lines are *like "001 h = 0.000000000000000E+00 e = 3.543218084205956E+00"* does not in any way disprove my assertion that they're being parsed as a filename. Spaces, newlines, and the other characters given are completely valid in filenames. If you want to disprove the assertion, **provide an actual full [mcve] that anyone here can run to see the problem themselves**,  or a full, non-excerpted, non-summarized `bash -x` log (though that should perhaps be off-site, as in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), as it's liable to be longer than appropriate here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes. That should be the problem. For each file, in addition to the lines given above, the lines like "001 h = 0.000000000000000E+00 e = 3.543218084205956E+00" are up to even 1000 lines based on the file ( with similar pattern).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157852/discussion-between-phenomenon-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: So, next issue is that the code causing that immediate issue isn't actually given in your question, making it easier impossible to resolve with only what's given here.